# Composing functions via map and flatmap

Tags: scala

I learn scala in university and I cannot understand how to use map, flatmap and Option. Here's couple functions from my lab. I know how to implement first but I have no idea how to deal with second? So, the question: how to implement second function without changing it's signature (using map and flatmap)?

```
def testCompose[A, B, C, D](f: A => B)
                           (g: B => C)
                           (h: C => D): A => D = h compose g compose f

def testMapFlatMap[A, B, C, D](f: A => Option[B])
                              (g: B => Option[C])
                              (h: C => D): Option[A] => Option[D] = // help
```

Comment: It is simple question but not sure if should answer. Advice: start implementation with `_.` then `ctrl+space` and determine what combination of map/flatmap calls have sense and compiles. I guess there is only one sensible solution.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It really becomes obvious after starting from _.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
_.flatMap(f).flatMap(g).map(h)
```

because:

- `_` - receive an `Option[A]`
- `flatMap(f)` - peek inside, return `Option[B]` (`flatMap()` won't re-wrap it)
- `flatMap(g)` - peek inside, return `Option[C]` (`flatMap()` won't re-wrap it)
- `map(h)` - peek inside, return D (`map()` will re-wrap it)

Comment: Or `_ flatMap f flatMap g map h` to match the previous method