# For comprehensions scala

Tags: scala, for-comprehension

I'm leaning scala and now I want to understand how to use for-comprensions for function composition. Here's a function which I should implement without changing it's signature. And I've almost done but I don't know how to deal with None in it. Could you tell me please how to modify this to get proper None handling? Or maybe I'm completely wrong and for-comprehensions are used in another way to compose functions in scala? Thanks.

```
 def testForComprehension[A, B, C, D](f: A => Option[B])
                            (g: B => Option[C])
                            (h: C => D): Option[A] => Option[D] = for { first <- _
                                                              second = f(first).get
                                                              third = g(second).get } yield h(third)
```

Comment: The problem is very trivial and I feels that giving you the answer would prevent you to understand what is happening and fix it on the future. Take a look to [how does yield work](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/yield.html) to understand how `for` is de sugared, it should become obvious at some point what you did wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for {
  a <- _
  b <- f(a)
  c <- g(b)
} yield h(c)
```

because for-comprehension is just a sugared version of jwvh's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60901300/5205022)

```
_.flatMap(f).flatMap(g).map(h)
```

Answer (score 1):

For comprehension is about `Option`, `List`, `Future` (anything that has methods like `map`, `flatMap` and `filter`) and not functions in particular. You should not do `.get` specially in a for-comprehension.

What you probably need is following

```scala
  def testForComprehension[A, B, C, D](
    f: A => Option[B]
  )(g: B => Option[C])(h: C => D): Option[A] => Option[D] = { v =>
    for {
      first <- v
      second <- f(first)
      third <- g(second)
    } yield h(third)
  }
```